# Installing latest CMake binaries on top of a jenkins Docker container

Tags: unix, cmake, dockerfile

I need to install a very recent version of CMake on top of a jenkins Docker container. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

# Install required plugins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

# Install CMake
RUN mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
RUN curl -L https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.13.1/cmake-3.13.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
```

When I start the `FROM`container interactive (`$ docker run -it jenkins/jenkins:lts bash`) I am able to install CMake to `$JENKINS_HOME/cmake`.

```
$ docker run -it jenkins/jenkins:lts bash
$ mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
$ curl -L https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.13.1/cmake-3.13.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   620    0   620    0     0    826      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   826
100 36.6M  100 36.6M    0     0  5485k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:-- 7581k
$ ls $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
```

However, when I try to build that image using `docker build`, the build fails:

```
...
Step 5/7 : RUN mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
 ---> Running in 6e8b914f2264
Removing intermediate container 6e8b914f2264
 ---> 24a75881d500
Step 6/7 : RUN curl -L https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.13.1/cmake-3.13.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -xz -C $JENKINS_HOME/cmake
 ---> Running in d1759df1fbdb
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   620    0   620    0     0    988      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   988
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0tar: /var/jenkins_home/cmake: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
  0 36.6M    0 50724    0     0  35123      0  0:18:13  0:00:01  0:18:12 82077
curl: (23) Failed writing body (2500 != 16360)
```

Running `whoami` from within the Dockerfile and from within the interactive session, both yields `jenkins`.

What is the main difference between both installation approaches and how can I install the latest CMake binaries using `docker build`?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/rikorose/gcc-cmake/dockerfile) it's a Dockerfile from `gcc` that installs the latest version of `cmake`, this is its content:

```
FROM gcc:5

RUN wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.17.2/cmake-3.17.2-Linux-x86_64.sh \
      -q -O /tmp/cmake-install.sh \
      && chmod u+x /tmp/cmake-install.sh \
      && mkdir /usr/bin/cmake \
      && /tmp/cmake-install.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr/bin/cmake \
      && rm /tmp/cmake-install.sh

ENV PATH="/usr/bin/cmake/bin:${PATH}"
```

I was looking for a solution to build XGboost for GPU usage inside a Docker and needed a `cmake` with the version above 3.12. This installation method works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't verify your solution, as I'm to far away from that problem currently. Maybe someone else can verify it.